# serverless-offline: Custom authorizer will not work if http_proxy is specified

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I want to use serverless-offline to authenticate with a custom authorizer.

The file serverless.yml is shown below.

```
functions:
  auth:
    handler: src/authorizer.handler

...
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 4000
    resourceRoutes: true
...

resources:
  Resources:
    ProxyResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: protected
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ProxyPathResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Ref: ProxyResource
        PathPart: "{proxy+}"
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ProxyPathMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: "CUSTOM"
        AuthorizerId:
          Ref: AuthApiGatewayAuthorizer
        ResourceId:
          Ref: ProxyPathResource
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        HttpMethod: ANY
        RequestParameters:
          method.request.path.proxy: false
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
          - StatusCode: 401
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
          Type: HTTP_PROXY
          Uri: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/{proxy}
          RequestParameters:
            integration.request.path.proxy: method.request.path.proxy
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
            - StatusCode: 401
```

Run it.

```
$ sls offline
...
offline: ANY /development/auth-test/{proxy*} -> https://my-json-server.typicode.com/{proxy}
offline: [HTTP] server ready: http://localhost:4000
```

After that, accessing the following uri will return a normal response.
The custom authorizer does not seem to be working.

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:4000/development/protected/typicode/demo/profile'
{"name": "typicode"}
```

Running curl through the api-gateway will result in 401

```
$ sls deploy
$ curl 'https://xxxx.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/development/protected/typicode/demo/profile' // This is a 401

$ curl 'https://xxxx.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/development/protected/typicode/demo/profile' --header 'Authorization: Bearer {valid_token}' // This is 200
```

Does serverless-offline go through authentication with http_proxy?

Pardon my broken English!

Comment: In the case of proxy, there is no auth in hapiOptions and it seems that it is not validated.
https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/blob/master/src/events/http/HttpServer.js#L976 ...